# Why is the type inference lost when union type is returned from function?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I am using the following union type:

```
interface A {
    type: 'A';
}

interface B {
    type: 'B';
    bProp: number
}

type X = A | B
```

When I am trying to use it in array and map over it, I get a compilation error:

```
let list: X[] = []
let list2: X[] = list.map(el => {
    return true ? { type: 'B', bProp: 1 } : el
    }
)

(39,5): Type '(A | { type: string; bProp: number; })[]' is not assignable to type 'X[]'.
  Type 'A | { type: string; bProp: number; }' is not assignable to type 'X'.
    Type '{ type: string; bProp: number; }' is not assignable to type 'X'.
      Type '{ type: string; bProp: number; }' is not assignable to type 'B'.
        Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"B"'.
```

However, when I extract the record of type to a local variable and explicitly type it, it works:

```
let list: X[] = []
let list2: X[] = list.map(el => {
        let tmp: B = { type: 'B', bProp: 1 };
        return true ? tmp : el
    }
)
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you initialize the field of object literal with a string contant the type of the field will be inferred as `string` not as the string literal type `B`, so `{ type: 'B' , bProp: 1 }` is typed as `{ type:string, bProp: number }` which is incompatible with `B`.

You can cast the string to the string literal type explicitly:

```
let list: X[] = []
let list2: X[] = list.map(el => {
    return true ? { type: 'B' as 'B', bProp: 1 } : el
})
```

The second example works because you explicitly type `tmp` to `B`, so then the compiler just checks that the object literal is compatible with the declared type of `B` it does not have to determine a type for `tmp`. This why this would also work:

```
let list2: X[] = list.map(el => {
    return true ? { type: 'B', bProp: 1 } as B : el
})
```